# Is it right to say "we were like fasting "?

Tags: discourse-markers

I think have heard some instances in colloquial English in which people use "like" along with ing-form verbs, for example, "We were like boiling of the heat".

I have written the following text from another language:

> Rasha had bruised below his eyes, we were like fasting for days [because there was no food].

I mean that we were so short of food reserves as if we were fasting. Is this {like+ing-form} a correct English usage?

Comment: Yes, *we were like something* means *we looked as if we were something*.  So in this case, *we looked like we were fasting for days*.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would choose to add this filler text to something that sounds like a very serious sentence. This is a very informal usage and I strongly recommend (personally) that everyone, regardless of whether they speak it natively or not, avoid it... Regardless, if you were to use it in the manner suggested below, it would be more common to place "like" before "days". "We were fasting for, like, days." This emphasizes the word "days".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Like* in your first example is not a comparator but a colloquial [*discourse marker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker), which acts to focus what immediately follows it. It has been characteristic of the language of young people for fifty years or so, and is pretty much confined to that speech community.

> I thought *The Matrix* was like awesome. Totally.

In your proposed sentence *like* has to be taken in this discourse marker sense. When you say that X is **like** Y, X and Y must be comparable entities; but in your sentence *we* designates persons while *fasting* is an action.

If you want to say that your enforced hunger was analogous to religious fasting, use *as if* or something of that sort, or use *like* in a syntactic context where it cannot be taken as the discourse marker.

> We went hungry for three days, as if we were fasting.
>   With almost no food, it was almost like fasting; we were constantly hungry.

Comment: In written language, I have typically seen the "like" offset by commas, as in: "I thought *The Matrix* was, like, awesome. Totally."

Comment: @Brian Yah, that's a convenient typographic device for marking it as a marker (!). But in speech there's no discernible pause before *like*, and rarely one after it.

Comment: Mmm... now that you point it out, I think I've actually heard it with both cadences--both with and without pauses before and after.  I would say the difference is the emotional intensity/aspect of the speaker. 'No pauses' gives a high intensity; 'with pauses' gives a more laconic feel.

Comment: @talmu Actually, it was about 'quotative like', which is a special instance of dm 'like', and it was funny, too.

Comment: @Charles I miss it. (see above)

Comment: Some people also use *like* as a filler, similar to *er* or *um*, as a noise to make while they think about what to say next.  And I have to say, *like* in either sense is pretty common among US speakers of my generation (born say 1975-1985), and it would be very generous to describe us as "young".

Comment: @NateEldredge Interesting. I'm of the generation in which dm *like* arose, but I work with people of all ages. My experience is that *like* tends to disappear from people's speech by the time they're about thirty; after that it is used only ironically. Perhaps it is a function of self-censorship in the work environment.

Comment: @Brian In my experience (which is, again, that of an older user), the pauses tend to be disfluency effects in which, as Nate Eldredge says, *like* is used as a filler, signalling that the speaker is despite the pause not yet finished